# HTTP Post request not going through in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to add an item to my Todoist project through an Alexa skill in AWS Lambda.  I am very new to all of these technologies so forgive me if the fix is incredibly obvious.  When I ask Alexa to invoke my addZipcode skill, it fails.  This is what I have (excluding some stuff that is in all Alexa Lambda functions):

```
Alexa stuff
...
const handlers = {
'LaunchRequest': function() {
    this.emit('AMAZON.HelpIntent');
},
'addZipcode': function() {

    const newZip = this.event.request.intent.slots.zipcode.value;
    const speechOutput = newZip;

    var http = require("https");
    function postZip(newZip) {
        var options = {
            "method": "POST",
            "hostname": [
                "beta",
                "todoist",
                "com"
            ],
            "path": [
                "API",
                "v8",
                "tasks"
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
            }
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            var chunks = [];
            res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            res.on("end", function() {
                var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                console.log(body.toString());
            });
        });
        req.write(JSON.stringify({ content: newZip, project_id: XXXXXXXXXX }));
        req.end();
    }

    postZip(newZip);

    this.response.cardRenderer(SKILL_NAME, newZip);
    this.response.speak(speechOutput);
    this.emit(':responseReady');

},
.... cont
```

I get the resulting error when I try to run the skill with Alexa:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "hostHeader.replace is not a function",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:130:39)",
    "new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:159:16)",
    "Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)",
    "Object.exports.request (https.js:199:15)",
    "postZip (/var/task/index.js:72:28)",
    "Object.addZipcode (/var/task/index.js:88:9)",
    "emitNone (events.js:86:13)",
    "AlexaRequestEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)",
    "AlexaRequestEmitter.EmitEvent (/var/task/node_modules/alexa-sdk/lib/alexa.js:216:10)",
    "AlexaRequestEmitter.ValidateRequest (/var/task/node_modules/alexa-sdk/lib/alexa.js:181:23)"
  ]
}
```

I tried searching for more information about hostHeader.replace or even just hostHeader but to no avail.  When I surround my postZip function with

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {}
```

the skill actually works, but the Post request does not go through (as in, the new zipcode is not added as a new task on my Todoist).  I'm pretty sure the Post request code itself is correct because I ran it through Postman and the zipcode was added.

Please help me understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what causes that error. But the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) say, that `hostname` as well as `path` are supposed to be nothing but strings and not arrays as it's the case in your code.

So what I'd do first is to change your code to this:

```
var options = {
        "method": "POST",
        "hostname": "beta.todoist.com",
        "path": "/API/v8/tasks",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
        }
```

Comment: huh, that's interesting! well it did get rid of the error in my post but now the new error is that it times out after about 7 seconds

Comment: Do you have the right auth token in place?
I would first assemble an API request that works with a tool like Postman and then dynamically implement that in my code.

Comment: @JackFlyer , I am exactly at that spot. I am trying to trigger a Gitlab pipeline but it is always timing out whatever I try. However, when I change the POST to GET and try to fetch 'google.com' it succeeds. Did you find a solution??